# Javascript Slideshow start on Mouse Hover Over

Tags: javascript, html

Following is my Javascript and Html Slideshow code which start the slide automatically. Now I'm trying to start this slide when **Mouse Hover Over** on it. But I can't.  Is it possible or how can i do this ?

**Html Head Section Javascript Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Html Body Section Code:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="example">          
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">                
                <div class="slide">
<a href="#"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 
1"></a>             
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
<a href="#"><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 
2"></a>                     
                </div>                      
            </div>              
        </div>
<img src="img/example-frame.png" width="739" height="341" alt="Example Frame" id="frame">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your function (rather than an anonymous `$(function(){ ...`) then calling it by name in the `onmouseover` event of one of your divs (either "slides" or "example" or "containiner")

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SlidesJS plugin?

http://www.slidesjs.com/